# Using JQuery to add or remove form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have been trying to get a function working with JQuery to add or subtract form input fields. I have been using an example I found as a starting point.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            // start a counter for new row IDs
            // by setting it to the number
            // of existing rows
            var newRowNum = 2;

            // bind a click event to the "Add" link
            $('#addnew').click(function(){
                // increment the counter
                newRowNum += 1;

                // get the entire "Add" row --
                // "this" refers to the clicked element
                // and "parent" moves the selection up
                // to the parent node in the DOM
                var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

                // copy the entire row from the DOM
                // with "clone"
                var newRow = addRow.clone();

                // set the values of the inputs
                // in the "Add" row to empty strings
                $('input', addRow).val('');
                $('name', addRow).val('os' + newRowNum);

                // replace the HTML for the "Add" link 
                // with the new row number
                $('td:first-child', newRow).html('<input type="hidden" name="on' + newRowNum + 'value="Email Address ' + newRowNum + '>Recipient');

                // insert a remove link in the last cell
                $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">Remove<\/a>');

                // loop through the inputs in the new row
                // and update the ID and name attributes
                $('input', newRow).each(function(i){
                    var newID = 'os' + newRowNum;
                    $(this).attr('id',newID).attr('name',newID);
                });

                // insert the new row into the table
                // "before" the Add row
                addRow.before(newRow);

                // add the remove function to the new row
                $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    return false;               
                });

                // prevent the default click
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The html is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr><td>
  Email Addresses</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Email Address 1"><a id="addnew" href="">Add</a></td><td><input name="os2" type="text" id="os2" value="" size="24" maxlength="60" /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I am confused about is why, when I look at the page in the browser, I see the extra input fields, but when I look at the source, the code for the extra fields are nowhere to be found.

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Dave

Answer (score 5):

> What I am confused about is why, when
>   I look at the page in the browser, I
>   see the extra input fields, but when I
>   look at the source, the code for the
>   extra fields are nowhere to be found.

That is becausethe browser shows you only the DOM as when the page is loaded.

You need [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Webdeveloper Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) (both Firefox Add-ons), and then you can see what jQuery did to modify your DOM.

Edit: there is also a [Webdeveloper Toolbar for Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

Comment: +1 for the IE Dev Toolbar, very handy ! I was actually looking for something like that but don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are looking at the source, it won't be there.
Such as in IE.  It will only report the page as it was before any javascript modified it.

Get firebug for firefox.  It will let you see everything.

Answer (score 0):

Those elements are dynamicly created, and therefore, are not found in the sourcecode. It's not that the sourcecode automaticly gets updated when you change it via javascript.

An firefox extension called [Web developers toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) has an option "View generated source" which shows you the source including dynamicly created elements.

Comment: Well, my problem is this: I am trying to send the values of these dynamically created fields to PayPal along with their appropriate name values and they are not being passed on at all. When a field is generated like this, are the values not passed in the POST array?

Dave

Comment: They should be; I use this technique in an application of mine. Are you sure those elements are actually appended to the form? Use tools like firebug to check this.

Comment: Well I found I had some errors in my logic and using WebDeveloper helped me see that. I will check with Firebug in a minute but perhaps you could help me with one last logic thing: I am using the following to try and loop through and set the name and id icrementally but it is not working. I might have the first-child.next-sibling thing wrong:

$('td:first-child.next-sibling.input', newRow).each(function(i){
     var newID = newRowNum;
     $(this).attr('id','os' + newID).attr('name','os' + newID);
    });

Dave