# Adding new input row to form on event click

Tags: javascript, input

[Using JQuery to add or remove form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564566/using-jquery-to-add-or-remove-form-elements/)

when i click the add link the information in the existing input field disappears.

How do i tell it to retain this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$('input', addRow).val('');
```

to

```
$('input', addRow).val($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

tried that Tim but what that does is move the info from the existing input and put it in the new row input instead.